# Is there any special name for a hash-function over a mutable collection?

Tags: python, data-structures, hash

Does it have any conventional naming?

It looks like I've reinvented the wheel or something, but I have no idea how to google this thing, so I had to write it from scratch (probably not in the most efficient way).

I've been working on a Leetcode task ([link](https://leetcode.com/problems/substring-with-concatenation-of-all-words/)), and I found it quite handy to use a hash function with the following features:

1. Working on mutable sequances of hashable (and immutable) objects:

   - `hash = MyHash(["cat", "dog", "pig"])`
2. Adding a new element to a sequance in O(1):

   - `hash.add("rat")`
3. Removing the element in O(1):

   - `hash.sub("pig")`
4. It should be order insensitive:

   - `assert MyHash(["cat", "dog", "rat"]) == MyHash(["rat", "dog", "cat"])`

The idea reminds me of the [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) concept, but then order insensitivity is not fulfilled.

The implementation is something like:

```py
class MyHash:
    MOD = int("1" * 19) # - prime, just in case

    def __init__(self, sequence=[]):
        self._hash_val = 0
        self._len = 0
        if sequence:
            for element in sequence:
                self.add(element)

    def add(self, element):
        self._len += 1
        self._hash_val += abs(hash(element))
        self._hash_val %= MyHash.MOD

    def sub(self, element):
        self._len -= 1
        self._hash_val -= abs(hash(element))
        self._hash_val %= MyHash.MOD

    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        return self._hash_val == __o._hash_val

    def __len__(self):
        return self._len
```

Comment: There are names for different ways of doing it, which generally depend on what kind of collection it is.  A Merkle hash is the most common example for ordered collections: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree, although both CRC and polynomial hashes also work, even if you need to insert/delete in the middle.  For unordered collections usually just the sum or XOR of all the element hashes is used.